# How would I bridge cast NSNumber to ABRecordID in iOS

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, abrecordref

I start learning programming with Objective-C, and do not have much knowledge of C. So, bridge casting in iOS 6 is still somewhat confusing for me.

Here is the scenario:

I have a person ABRecordID stored in CoreData as 'NSNumber' attribute. Later on, I would like to access to that person directly, so I want to use the person's ABRecordID to access the contact info using ABAddressBook. Noticed that `ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID` needs ABRecordID, below is how I perform casting in my code...

```
address_book = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordID rec_id = (__bridge ABRecordID)person.record_id;
```

However, This was not successful and I was given `incompatible types casting 'int' into 'ABRecordID' (aka 'int') with a __bridge cast`.

Already confused as it is, what would be a proper way to bridge cast between ARC type and CF type?

Also, in which case should I use `(__bridge retained)` instead of `(__bridge)`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `ABRecordID` is a synonym (typedef) for `int32_t` which is a 32-bit integer. So typecasting is not the proper approach. You want to create an `NSNumber` with the value of the id.

```
ABRecordId rec_id = person.record_id;
NSNumber *wrapper = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)rec_id];
```

and later:

```
NSNumber *wrapper = ...
ABRecordId rec_id = (ABRecordId)[wrapper intValue];
```

Please note that bridging and ARC are irrelevant when going to/from ABRecordId and NSNumber. There is no use of any of the `CF` types in this case. You'll know when you are using `CF` types because you'll have a variable whose type begins with `CF` (such as `CFArrayRef`).

Comment: Thank you! I am more interested in understanding typedef and all. All I know is that they are a type of C data structure. Could you please recommend some reading material where I can study its integration to Objective-C?

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C. There are a million books or web resources that will teach you C.

Comment: How do you convert a ABRecordId to an Int in Swift?